# Connect to AWS MySQL database from desktop application

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a desktop application which is written in JavaScript and HTML. I want to create a registration page that will connect to the AWS MYSQL database instance. How do I do this? I tried to search for resources but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a server-side script that listens for POST and GET requests from your website and based on the action it can query and add to the database. You can achieve this in PHP, Python, NodeJS and the term is called a RESTful implementation.